# Preparing for a flash crowd on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently experienced a sharp, short-lived increase in the load of my service on Google App Engine. The load went from ~1-2 req/second to about 10 req/second for about a couple of hours. My number of dynamic instances scaled up pretty quickly but in the process I did get a number of "Request waited too long" timeout messages.

So the next time around, I would like to be prepared with enough idle instances to handle my load. But now the question is, how do I determine how many is adequate. I expect a much larger burst in load this time - from practically nothing to an average of 500 requests/second, possibly with a peak of 3000. This is to last between 15 minutes and 1 hour.

My main goal is to ensure that the information passed via HTTP Post is saved to the datastore by means of a single write.

Here are the steps I have taken to prepare for the burst:

1. I have pruned the fast path to disable analytics and other reporting, which typically generate 2 urlfetch requests.
2. The datastore write is to be deferred to a taskqueue via the deferred library

What I would like to know is:
 1. Tips/insights into calculating how many idle instances one would need per N requests/second.
 2. It seems that the maximum throughput of a task queue is 500/second. Is this the rate at which you can push tasks, and if not, then is there a cap on that? I'm guessing not, since these are probably just datastore writes, but I would like to be sure.

My fallback plan if I am not confident of saving all of the information for this flash mob is to set up a beefy Amazon EC2 instance, run a web server on it and make my clients send a backup request to this server.

Comment: When you do your datastore write are you writing different entities for each request or the same entity for many requests (e.g. a counter). If the latter, many datastore writes within a second could cause contention and cause errors similar to what you describe. You would need to shard the data being recorded.

Comment: Peter, I am using Python. Ryan, there is no contention. The writes are not transactional.

Comment: Are you offloading the write to a taskqueue?

Comment: @stevep: Yes, the write is being offloaded via the deferred library.

Comment: The question has been updated to include the information in these comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must understand that Idle Instances are only used when new frontend instances are being spun-up. This means that they are only used during traffic increases. When traffic is steady they are not used.

Now if your instance needs 20 sec to spin up and can handle 10 req/sec of steady traffic and you traffic INCREASE is 5 req/sec, then you'll need 20 * 5 / 10 = 10 idle instances if you don't want any requests dropped.

What you should do is:

1. Maximize instance throughput (number of requests it can handle): optimize code, use async db operations and enable [Concurrent Requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests).
2. Minimize your instance startup time. This is important because idle instances are used during spinning up of new instances and the time it takes to spin up a new instance directly relates to how many idle instances you need. If you use Java this means getting rid of any heavy frameworks that do classpath scanning (Spring, etc..).

Fourth, number of frontend instances needed is VERY application specific. But since you already had traffic increase you should know how many requests your frontend instance can handle per second.

**Edit:** There is one more obvious thing you should do: HTTP caching. GAE has a [transparent HTTP cache](http://davepeck.org/2011/10/25/a-word-on-app-engine-caching/) which can be simply controlled via `Cache-Control` headers.

Also, if analytics has a big performance impact on your server, consider using client side analytics services (like Google Analytics). They also work for devices.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify a couple of things:
1. To what extent can concurrent requests help? Is it the case that without concurrent requests, the maximum rate of requests per instance = 1/app latency? So with concurrent requests if the box in use has multiple cores, the performance scales up?
2. Do you have a reference that documents that idle instances are not used in steady state?

Comment: 1. I believe artificial limit is 10 parallel requests - so it could be 10x faster. Yes, with single request you get 1/app latency. Even without multicores it scales up because your code spends much time waiting for APIs (db, memcache, etc..)

Comment: 2. That's why they are called "idle": https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#scheduler You can see them marked as "Resident" in you instance view in GAE Admin. Also in steady traffic they will handle no traffic as seen by the QPS value in this table.